# Concatenate two node values with a comma

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform the XML and am having some issues...

**Current XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Employees>
  <Employee>
   <ManagerFirstName>Joe</ManagerFirstName>
   <ManagerLastName>Schmoe</ManagerLastName>
  </Employee>
 </Employees>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Employees>
  <Employee>
   <supervisorName>Schmoe, Joe</supervisorName>
  </Employee>
 </Employees>
```

**Current XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" >
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ManagerFirstName">
        <supervisorName>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:value-of  select="/ManagerLastName"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/ManagerFirstName"/>
        </supervisorName>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is not working and I can not figure it out. The XML it is outputting at the moment looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Employees>
  <Employee>
   <supervisorName>Joe, </supervisorName>
   <ManagerLastName>Schmoe/ManagerLastName>
  </Employee>
 </Employees>
```

I feel like I'm so close...

**UPDATE**
How would I go about making sure that if ManagerFirstName and ManagerLastName are blank, that supervisorName does not have the comma inside of it?

**UPDATE 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/> <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Employee">
   <tbl_EmployeeList><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></tbl_EmployeeList>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="tbl_EmployeeList">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       <supervisorName>
         <xsl:value-of select="(ManagerLastName,ManagerFirstName)" separator=", "/>
       </supervisorName>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You should take advantage of XSLT 2.0 and use the `separator` attribute in `xsl:value-of`. Please see my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.  In the `ManagerFirstName` template you need a slightly different XPath to pull out the last name:

```
<xsl:template match="ManagerFirstName">
    <supervisorName>
        <xsl:value-of select="../ManagerLastName"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </supervisorName>
</xsl:template>
```

(the `apply-templates` is sufficient to give you the value of the `ManagerFirstName`, you don't need a specific `value-of` for that).  You then need a no-op template to stop it copying the last name independently

```
<xsl:template match="ManagerLastName" />
```

Also note that the usual identity template would match and apply-templates to `@*|node()` rather than just `node()` - it makes no difference in your example document because you're not using any attributes, but if your original XML had attributes then your version of the identity template would drop them.

Comment: A good solution, but I think preferable to following-sibling::ManagerLastName would be ../ManagerLastName. Not only is it briefer but it removes positional dependency

Comment: This worked great! Except, I need it to remove the ManagerLastName node after doing it's work... what would that look like?

Comment: @jpm0004 That's the purpose of the `<xsl:template match="ManagerLastName" />` - "if you find a ManagerLastName, ignore it".

Comment: Just now getting my coffee this morning... Thanks Ian works great!

Comment: One more thing Ian, because I am bound to only using XML 1.0 and you have addressed that, how could I make sure nothing is outputted if both the ManagerFirstName and ManagerLastName is missing?

Comment: @jpm0004 The version of XML has nothing to do with it. You can be sure of what you ask simply by testing it.

Comment: As DevNull suggested, this method works great along with a <xsl:if test="../ManagerLastName/text()"> in order to accomplish everything I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0 you can use the `separator` attribute in `xsl:value-of`...

**XML Input**

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <ManagerFirstName>Joe</ManagerFirstName>
        <ManagerLastName>Schmoe</ManagerLastName>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <supervisorName>
                <xsl:value-of select="(ManagerLastName,ManagerFirstName)" separator=", "/>
            </supervisorName>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Employees>
   <Employee>
      <supervisorName>Schmoe, Joe</supervisorName>
   </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Note: If there is no `ManagerLastName` or `ManagerFirstName`, no separator will be output.

Comment: Look again, I am using XML 1.0. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @jpm0004 - Not the XML version, the XSLT version. Your stylesheet is using 2.0: `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">`

Comment: I've tried this method, since I needed the ability to keep the separator from being output when there is no ManagerLastName or ManagerFirstName. Howevever, I came across an error: Expected token ')', found ','. Any ideas as to the problem?

Comment: @jpm0004 - Can you paste a copy of the `xsl:value-of` you're using? Also, what XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Alright, see Update 2 of the OP. I fixed the error I was getting (forgot that earlier in the XSL I had changed the root name), now the problem is that my output for supervisorName is <supervisorName>Joe</supervisorName>. It's like it doesn't understand the select and seperator. As far as the processor I am using, I am not sure. It is Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @jpm0004 - XSLT 2.0 isn't available by default in Visual Studio. You'll have to use a different processor. Saxon has a .NET implementation that you can use. http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ If you don't want to use XSLT 2.0, you can just wrap an `xsl:if` around the first `xsl:value-of` and `xsl:text` in Ian Roberts' answer. (Just use `../ManagerLastName` for the test.)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <Employee>
            <supervisorName><xsl:value-of select="concat(ManagerLastName, ', ', ManagerFirstName)"/></supervisorName>
        </Employee>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good solution, but it would be better to use literal sequence constructors rather that xsl:element. Also you don't need to specify text() as the node to string coercion will achieve that automatically.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a fully "push style" solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Employee">
  <supervisorName><xsl:apply-templates/></supervisorName>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Employee/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(', ', .)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Employee/*[1]"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

All responses seem good, but I think that this approach is cleaner (Just replace your ManagerFirstName template by this one):

```
<xsl:template match="Employee">
    <supervisorName>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(ManagerLastName,', ',ManagerFirstName)"/>
    </supervisorName>
</xsl:template>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to make the comma appear only if both nodes exist and are not empty you can use an if with string-length for that:

```
<xsl:template match="Employee">
    <supervisorName>
        <xsl:value-of select="ManagerLastName"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(ManagerLastName) and string-length(ManagerFirstName)">
            <xsl:text> ,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="ManagerFirstName"/>
    </supervisorName>
</xsl:template>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Yet a cleaner solution following xslt 2.0 approach, but which also covers the case of an empty node.

```
<xsl:template match="Employee">
    <supervisorName>
        <xsl:value-of select="(ManagerLastName[text()],ManagerFirstName[text()])" separator=", "/>
    </supervisorName>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's almost exactly the same as the answer from @LukaszBaran. (Except you have the order of the names swapped.)

Comment: You are right, I think I skipped that one. Anyway, last update of OP changes the request.

Comment: Your update is almost exactly like my answer except you drop the original `Employee` element. Good idea though. :-)